# Hibernate flushing old object state

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently, I have a thread which retrieves an object from the database, manipulates it and commits it. However, after this happens Hibernate will attempt to flush (on the same thread) with the state of the object before manipulation, which fortunately fails due to the data being stale.
The below snippet is where the entity is modified and committed, which works just fine, however database logs indicate that just after this happens, the HibernateTransactionManager attempts to flush it's state, which it believes corresponds to how the entity was represented before the below snippet was executed.

```
TransactionStatus tx = createNewTransaction();
Entity current = Entity.findById(entityId);
if(shouldProceed(current)){
    current.setResult(newResult);
    ...
    Entity.persist(current);
    commit(tx);
}
```

Entity.findById(Long id) calls get(Class clazz, Serializable id) on the Session.
Entity.persist(Entity e) calls Session.saveOrUpdate(T entity), and from there does not appear to call any non-Hibernate code.
commit(TransactionStatus tx) uses AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(TransactionStatus status), and does not use any functionality specific to our code (beyond exception handling).

shouldProceed(Entity e) does not modify the entity state, and there is no explicit call to flush the state after this happens.
How is the old state being used by Hibernate as what it should flush, when the state in Hibernate should have been updated for the entity?

Comment: It is strange your code snippet. You should use EntityManager `merge` method somewhere. I see only `Entity.persist(current);`

Comment: Unfortunately I have to omit certain parts of the code, however I'll update with what I can.

Comment: Could you go into more detail regarding how entities are being fetched and maybe reveal the code behind Entity.persist()? Your approach strikes me as rather unorthodox and manual transaction handling is tricky either way, so it is hard to make out possible caveats without more information...

Comment: Both persist and findById are in the OP now. They both call methods on the Hibernate Session, so unless they are calling different sessions I am confused.

Comment: Unless you are somehow attaching your transaction to the session (which may not even be possible and I cannot see you doing that) I believe you have in fact two transactions running. Since you're closing the first created transaction after making changes through your second tx / session it makes sense if the first transaction contains stale data. If you absolutely must handle sessions yourself, you should be starting a new transaction by calling Transaction tc = session.beginTransaction();